# Numpy 2D array indexing without out of bound and with clipping value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

I have indices array

```
a = np.array([
   [0, 0],
   [1, 1],
   [1, 9]
])
```

And 2D array

```
b = np.array([
   [0, 1, 2, 3],
   [5, 6, 7, 8]
])
```

I can do this one

```
b[a[:, 0], a[:, 1]]
```

But it'll be an exception '**out of bounds**', because 9 is out of range. 
I need a *very fast way* to make array slice by indices and it will be ideal if I can set a clip value, e.g.:

```
np.indexing_with_clipping(array=b, indices=a, clipping_value=0)
> array([0, 6, --> 0 = clipped value <--])
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach -

```
def indexing_with_clipping(arr, indices, clipping_value=0):
    idx = np.where(indices < arr.shape,indices,clipping_value)
    return arr[idx[:, 0], idx[:, 1]]
```

Sample runs -

```
In [266]: arr
Out[266]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])

In [267]: indices
Out[267]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 9]])

In [268]: indexing_with_clipping(arr,indices,clipping_value=0)
Out[268]: array([0, 6, 5])

In [269]: indexing_with_clipping(arr,indices,clipping_value=1)
Out[269]: array([0, 6, 6])

In [270]: indexing_with_clipping(arr,indices,clipping_value=2)
Out[270]: array([0, 6, 7])

In [271]: indexing_with_clipping(arr,indices,clipping_value=3)
Out[271]: array([0, 6, 8])
```

---

With focus on memory and performance efficiency, here's an approach that modifies the indices within the function -

```
def indexing_with_clipping_v2(arr, indices, clipping_value=0):
    indices[indices >= arr.shape] = clipping_value
    return arr[indices[:, 0], indices[:, 1]]
```

Sample run -

```
In [307]: arr
Out[307]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3],
       [5, 6, 7, 8]])

In [308]: indices
Out[308]: 
array([[0, 0],
       [1, 1],
       [1, 9]])

In [309]: indexing_with_clipping_v2(arr,indices,clipping_value=2)
Out[309]: array([0, 6, 7])
```

Comment: How about `np.take`?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this one "np.where(indices < arr.shape,indices,clipping_value)" - is very slow operation for my task :((

Comment: @hpaulj yes, I know about np.take, but there are two problems: 1) no clipping value, 2) only 1D arrays...

Comment: @MaxTkachenko Would you mind if the original indices array `a` is modified within the function?

Comment: @MaxTkachenko Also, what are the typical shapes of `a` and `b` in your actual use-case?

Comment: Original indices array a can be modified within the function, it's ok. a.shape = [N, 2], b.shape=[K, L]. b is an image and a are pixels I need to use.

Comment: @MaxTkachenko Check out the updated version. Also info on typical shapes of a and b might help us.

Answer (score 2):

You can use list comprehension:

```
b[
    [min(x,len(b[0])-1) for x in a[:,0]],
    [min(x,len(b[1])-1) for x in a[:,1]]
]
```

**edit** I used last array value as your clipping value, but you can replace the `min()` function with whatever you want (e.g. trenary operator)

**edit2** OK, based on clarification in comments and all python-fu that I could put together, this snipped finally does what you need:

```
clipping_value = -1
tmp=np.append(b,[[clipping_value],[clipping_value]],axis=1)
tmp[zip(*[((x,y) if (x<b.shape[0] and y<b.shape[1]) else (0,b.shape[1])) for (x,y) in zip(a.transpose()[0],a.transpose()[1])])]
```

It is the same as above, just creates ndarray `tmp`, which is a copy of `b` but contains the `clipping_value` as its last element and then uses my previous solution to set indices so, that they point to the last element if either of the indices is bigger than dimensions of `b`.

I learned that there is reverse to the `zip` function and that the numpy arrays accept lists as indices. It was fun. Thanks.

Comment: I think this is not bad idea and np.clip() is more fast solution here. Thanks :)

Comment: @MaxTkachenko But `.clip()` won't let you set `clipping_value`, right?

Comment: @Divakar I mean to use np.clip() instead of [min(x,len(b[0])-1) for x in a[:,0]] to avoid slow "for".

Comment: @MaxTkachenko i see your problem now, my approach only lets you select a value from your original array and clip will be indeed faster.

Comment: @MaxTkachenko see my latest edit. is this what you need?